# Simulate the choose option inside PowerShell script

Tags: powershell, chef-infra

I am installing a monitoring agent using PowerShell script that asks me to choose from a set of option during running the script ( Luckily the option I need is the default one, so when running manually I just press " Enter " and it proceeds.

Now I am using the below script and it shows the option to choose after the last line. How can I simulate the Enter button so the script finished successfully. I tried to use the below sendkeys(~) code but it is not working.

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = 'tls12, tls'
        (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile("https://github.com/newrelic/newrelic-cli/releases/latest/download/NewRelicCLIInstaller.msi", "$env:TEMP\\NewRelicCLIInstaller.msi")
        
        msiexec.exe /qn /i $env:TEMP\\NewRelicCLIInstaller.msi | Out-Null


        
        $env:NEW_RELIC_API_KEY='NRAKABC'
        $env:NEW_RELIC_ACCOUNT_ID='ABC'
        

        # I Think it is prompting for input when userdata reaches this point
        & 'C:\\Program Files\\New Relic\\New Relic CLI\\newrelic.exe' install --skipLoggingInstall

    $wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell;
$wshell.AppActivate('Administrator: Windows PowerShell')
Sleep 1
        
$wshell.SendKeys('~')
```

I am inserting the above script inside chef recipe and running from there. Any idea how can I resolve this. TIA

Comment: Assuming you can modify the script, try adding the `-y` option to the `newrelic.exe` call  - see https://github.com/newrelic/newrelic-cli/blob/main/docs/cli/newrelic_install.md - which is more robust than trying to send keystrokes.

Comment: @mklement0 I have to also insert the hostname, user and password during the installation. So can i pass it like this - hostname -pass ??

Comment: I have no experience with this utility, but perhaps the linked documentation helps.

Comment: @mklement0 thanks. I think thats not for new relic thats a egenral question. Like during installation it asks me  " Enter Hostname :   " Now how can I automate it by giving argument like you said with -y . Will something like this work -hostname myhostname ?

Comment: Every CLI is free to make up its own parameters, unfortunately, so you'll have to consult a given CLI's documentation. As for your `SendKeys` attempt as shown in the question: that likely comes _too late_, because `newrelic.exe` presumably runs _synchronously_, which means that the `SendKeys` call isn't reached until `newrelic.exe` has terminated (which it won't by itself, if a keystroke is needed).

Answer (score 0):

So the solution is that we have to pass the -y after we are installing the new relic infrastructure agent. -y assumes all yes when you pass it.

No need to simulate the enter by using the send key method or any other method. The below code is working fine.

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = 'tls12, tls'
        (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile("https://github.com/newrelic/newrelic-cli/releases/latest/download/NewRelicCLIInstaller.msi", "$env:TEMP\\NewRelicCLIInstaller.msi")
        
        msiexec.exe /qn /i $env:TEMP\\NewRelicCLIInstaller.msi | Out-Null


        
        $env:NEW_RELIC_API_KEY='NRAKABC'
        $env:NEW_RELIC_ACCOUNT_ID='ABC'
        

        # I Think it is prompting for input when userdata reaches this point
        & 'C:\\Program Files\\New Relic\\New Relic CLI\\newrelic.exe' install -y 
    --skipLoggingInstall
```